# Android Navigation Component's Argument Value cannot take in String Resource?

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I have the below code for my navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:name="com.elyeproj.bottombarfragmentsswitching.ContainerFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_notifications"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_container" >
        <argument
            android:name="FragmentKey"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="@string/title_notifications" />
        <argument
            android:name="FragmentColor"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="#00FFFF" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Where `@string/title_notifications` will return `Notifications`

However, it errors out at the `android:defaultValue="@string/title_notifications"`

```
        <argument
            android:name="FragmentKey"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="@string/title_notifications" />
```

The error is

```
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unsupported value 'Notifications' for string. You must use a "reference" type to reference other resources.
```

The `@string/title_notifications` definitely has value `Notifications`, as it is used fine in the `fragment` tag.

If I convert to

```
        <argument
            android:name="FragmentKey"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="Notifications" />
```

Then it compiles fine.

Why can't the `argument` tag use String resource?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I have to use the `reference` type instead. I cannot mix String and Reference

```
        <argument
            android:name="FragmentKey"
            app:argType="reference"
            android:defaultValue="@string/title_notifications" />
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `android:name="@string/fragment_key"` for the `argument` tag? - just in case we want to unify it and use it in multiple xmls, and in code also.